# Flow is not collected from room after an update

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-flow, kotlin-stateflow

I am currently migrating an android application from XML, Databinding and Flow/LiveData to Compose, Flow/StateFlow.

In this application, I have a very simple Room database:

```kotlin
@Entity
data class User(@PrimaryKey var id: Int = 0, var name: String)
```

```kotlin
@Dao
interface UserDAO
{

  @Query("Select * from User where id = :userId")
  fun getUserFlow(userId: Int): Flow<User?>

  @Transaction
  @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
  suspend fun createNewUser(user: User)

  @Transaction
  @Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
  suspend fun updateUser(user: User)

}
```

```kotlin
@Database(
  entities = [User::class],
  version = 1,
  exportSchema = true
)
abstract class UserDatabase
  : RoomDatabase()
{

  abstract fun userDao(): UserDAO

}
```

From a `ViewModel`, I create, update and collect the data from the database:

```kotlin
class MainViewModel(application: Application)
  : AndroidViewModel(application)
{

  private val userDatabase by lazy { Room.databaseBuilder(application, UserDatabase::class.java, "user-data.db").build() }

  private val user = userDatabase.userDao().getUserFlow(0).stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000), null)

  val name = user.map {
    it?.name ?: "no name"
  }.stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000), "pouet")

  fun create()
  {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
      userDatabase.userDao().createNewUser(User(name = "Test"))
    }
  }

  fun update()
  {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
      user.value?.name = UUID.randomUUID().toString()

      user.value?.let {
        userDatabase.userDao().updateUser(it)
      }
    }
  }

}
```

And then I collect the StateFlow using `collectAsStateWithLifecycle` into the activity:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity()
{

  private val model: MainViewModel by viewModels()

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
      MyApplicationTheme {
        val name = model.name.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

        Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
          Button(
            onClick = { model.create() }) {
            Text("Create")
           }
          Button(
            onClick = { model.update() }) {
            Text("Update")
          }
          Text(
            text = "Hello ${name.value}!",
          )
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I click on the create button, the user is inserted in the database but the UI is not updated.

When I click on the update button, the user name is updated correctly in the database but the UI is not updated.

Using Android Studio, if I change directly the user name in the database, the UI is correctly updated.

I do not understand why the StateFlow is correctly collected when I update manually the database using Android Studio but it does not work when the database is updated using the code.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You’re passing 0 as the Id of the user you create, which IIRC tells SQLite to generate an ID of its own choosing, which means the first time it’s called, the first user will have ID 1. The second time it’s called, the new user will have ID 2, and so on. You’re requesting the row of the database with ID 0. I’m not sure if there’s a defined behavior for that but I would expect you to get a flow of `null` only. However, I’m rusty so maybe everything I’m saying is wrong. I would expect the exact same behavior if you were using LiveData instead of Flows.

Comment: Hello, This code is just a sample one in order to illustrate the issue. In database the ID is 0. And as I said, if I change the name of the user in the database using the "app inspection" tab from Android Studio, using the same SQL request with the ID 0, it works. The UI is updated. It does not work when the database is updated from the coroutine.